# Check if bluetooth is being used from another app

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I have tried using **CBCentralManagerDelegate** **centralManagerDidUpdateState method** but I didn't get anything when bluetooth is used by other apps. When bluetooth is turned on or off it will notify me.

```
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    switch central.state {
    case .poweredOn:
        bluetoothTurnedOn()
        break
    case .poweredOff:
        bluetoothTurnedOFF()
        break
    case .resetting:
        break
    case .unauthorized:
        break
    case .unsupported:
        break
    case .unknown:
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Is there any way to detect if bluetooth is in use from another app, or even by OS?

Comment: No, you can't. The info you have is in fact more "Is the BLE Cheap is on/off/resetting/unsupported etc."

Comment: @Larme Thank you :D